# Как избавиться от расширения файла?

Tags: java, servlet

Привет, помогите сделать такую штуку, у меня есть форма, просто форма, код ее такой:

```
<form action="searchf" method="Post">
<input type="text" name="text" autofocus >
<input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Пользователь вводит в эту форму различные имена файлов, например: index.txt, hello.html (файлов с повторяющимися именами нет). Далее в сервлете string принимает, что ввел пользователь

```
String myName = request.getParameter("text");
```

И далее программа по имени введенного файла ищет эти файлы в папке, но дело в том, что надо вводить именно index.html, а не просто index, вот помогите, чтобы расширение вводить необязательно, пытался сделать так,

```
String myNamee = request.getParameter("text");
String myName = myNamee.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
```

не получилось(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я правильно понял - нужно "отрезать" расширение?

`index.html` превратить в `index` ?

Ну тогда вариант есть такой:

```
String name = "index.html";
name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")); // "index"
```